# PHP - Select array based on value of which is within array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to select a specific array within an array without using a number position. The reason I don't want to a use a number position because the position will not always be equal based on the user logged in.

For instance, with the following array, I want to select only that of which has the `x` value of `YourPhone`.

The array structure:

```
$salesArray = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'Basic Planners',
        'values' => array(
            array('x' => 'YourPhone', 'y' => 150),
            array('x' => 'Universe X3', 'y' => 300),
            array('x' => 'ePhone 74s', 'y' => 1500),
            array('x' => 'NextUs', 'y' => 50),
            array('x' => 'Humanoid', 'y' => 500)
        )
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'No-Namers',
        'values' => array(
            array('x' => 'YourPhone', 'y' => 300),
            array('x' => 'Universe X3', 'y' => 250),
            array('x' => 'ePhone 74s', 'y' => 400),
            array('x' => 'NextUs', 'y' => 150),
            array('x' => 'Humanoid', 'y' => 900)
        )
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'Feature Followers',
        'values' => array(
            array('x' => 'YourPhone', 'y' => 359),
            array('x' => 'Universe X3', 'y' => 900),
            array('x' => 'ePhone 74s', 'y' => 100),
            array('x' => 'NextUs', 'y' => 500),
            array('x' => 'Humanoid', 'y' => 250)
        )
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'Hipsters & Elites',
        'values' => array(
            array('x' => 'YourPhone', 'y' => 200),
            array('x' => 'Universe X3', 'y' => 350),
            array('x' => 'ePhone 74s', 'y' => 50),
            array('x' => 'NextUs', 'y' => 800),
            array('x' => 'Humanoid', 'y' => 100)
        )
    )
  );
```

Right now I'm selecting the values as such:

```
<?php $currentTeam = 0; ?>

 <table>
   <?php foreach ($sales as $sale) { ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $sale['key']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $sale['values'][$currentTeam]['y']; ?></td>
     </tr>
   <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate the extra mile in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want that particular key, just use an `if` condition to check, if it matches then print. Like this: [**Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2dfLRa)

```
<?php $needle = 'YourPhone'; ?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($salesArray as $sale) { ?>
        <?php
        $key = null;
        foreach($sale['values'] as $index => $info) {
            if($info['x'] == $needle) {
            // if(stripos($info['x'], $needle) !== false) {
                $key = $index;
                break;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $sale['key']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $sale['values'][$key]['y']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code block solves it:

**MODIFIED**

```
$currentTeam = "YourPhone"; ?>

 <table>
   <?php foreach ($salesArray as $sale) { ?>

     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $sale['key']; ?></td>
       <td><?php
            foreach($sale['values'] as $values){
                if($values['x'] == $currentTeam )
                    echo $values['y'];
            }

        ?>
        </td>
     </tr>
   <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

You need to use another foreach to get full control on the next array.